# What are the Alternatives to Google Analytics

Tags: seo, web-analytics, user-tracking

I need to Track Unique Visitor count in my web application. I would really like to use Google Analytics but due to the Load limitations that google imposes I will not be able to use them. I am expecting WAY over 10,000 requests a day. This is the limitation that Google web analytics API imposes. Is there another company that has the same features as google analytics that is paid or free?

Comment: Why are you making over 10000 requests per day?  Surely if you request every minute it would be more than sufficient.

Comment: I am expecting my site to grow more than 100,000 pages. According to google limitations I can only request 1000 items/pages at a time with a max of 10,000. So I can request 1000 pages for the first page then 1000 for the 2nd page but i cant request the 11th page because it will be over 10,000 entries.

Comment: There are [several alternatives](https://wpslimseo.com/free-google-analytics-alternatives/) which are open-source or free on cloud with limitations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There definitely are.

Here are two open source and free solutions that are very polished:

[Piwik](http://piwik.org/) - Designed as a direct competitor to Google Analytics (it looks just as nice) that you host on your own servers

[Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/)

Comment: I took a look at Piwik. Can Piwik filter visits from a robot and search engines?

Answer (score 5):

the 10,000 request apply to the Data API, not to the actual data collection.

Like you can have an unlimited number of users seeing your website. On the other hand if you use the API to extract data from their database, you can do 10k request a day only.

check this [link](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html) for more details

Comment: Yes..I will be downloading tracking information into my own database and it will contain over 10,000 pages. I must get this information daily for every page.

Comment: I see, do you need a javascript based solution or a log parsing tool would be ok ?

Comment: I can use eiter as long as it has an api were i can download statistics in my own database.

Comment: what figures you exactly needs pageview ? orther things?

Comment: I just need something similar to google analytics with similar features. But I must have an api so I can programmatically pull the information

Answer (score 2):

The biggest, most obvious, most usual alternative is to simply do it yourself.  Your webserver needs to log requests for security etc. anyway, so it's not a big deal to run something like webalizer on those logs.  You won't get the quick, easy access to advanced information like paths users take through the site, btu that can be determined if you care enough.  You do gain one huge benefit though: privacy of your own data.

Answer (score 0):

We use Omniture here but it'll cost you.

Comment: Yes..I have already spoken to omniture and they said they will charge me $1000/month for the features I need. I can't afford that. I also talked to visistat, they are much cheaper but they don't have a mature API.

Comment: Wow, yeah they're not cheap but the stuff you get out of them is actually pretty good.  I work for a corporate so i never knew they cost that much.  Insane!  For that price you could write one in a couple of weeks/months.  :)

Answer (score 0):

There is [SpeedTrap](http://www.speed-trap.com/), a java-based analytics package. Our company used it for years before they turned into cheap ****ards and decided Google Analytics was more cost effective (because it was free). But that's a story for another night.