# What Web Analytics Sites/Software Have a Good API Besides Google Analytics

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-analytics, web-analytics-tools

I cannot use Google analytics because of their limitations on the API. They will not allow me to query more then 10,000 entries in one day. Since I have more then 10,000 pages Google Analytics will not work for me unless there is a way around that 10,000 limitation. I need to pull statistics on all my pages daily and it will be over 10,000 pages

I have already tried:

- **OmniTure:** too Expensive -- 1000/month
- **Visistat:** API is not mature enough
- **Piwik:** API not mature enough
- **Programming it myself:** Will take too long and will require more resources from my server

Comment: A slightly updated duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541375/what-are-the-alternatives-to-google-analytics by the same author?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be impractical given the size of your site and the extent of the analytics you require, but have you considered analysing the raw IIS logfiles? Either suck them into SQL for processing or use a third party product like [WebTrends Log Analyser](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/win/7922).

Answer (score 1):

[Webtrends](http://www.webtrends.com/Products/Analytics/API.aspx) has an API.

Answer (score 0):

ClickTracks (now called Lyris HQ Web Analytics) is pretty cool, kind of the OG Google Analytics

http://www.lyris.com/solutions/lyris-hq/web-analytics/

Answer (score 0):

[Urchin](https://secure.urchin.com/helpwiki/en/Data_API) has a REST and SOAP interface to the API. The API was just released in version 6.6 of Urchin, and will no doubt get more mature in the future.

There is a one off cost to get Urchin, but this cost would be trivial if you are looking to keep track of statistics for a 10,000 page website.

There are other advantages of Urchin over GA, such as your statistics can be updated hourly instead of GA's daily.

Comment: Urchin pretty much is GA--they bought the company and google now sells the product.

Comment: Urchin was discontinued in 2012, unfortunately.  We now use Angelfish.