# Paypal sandbox test credit card numbers

Tags: paypal

Paypal support forums keep mentioning about getting a credit card number automatically. However, it does not show any credit card information automatically anymore - I tried 100 times.

I searched on internet, a famous link `paypalobjects.com` popups and all the credit card numbers have been linked to the maximum accounts.

How and where do I find a fake Visa/Master Credit card number that I can use for sandbox paypal account?

I am so screwed up! Please help!

Comment: Thank you for your question even though it wasn't very StackOverflowy. It's nice to know I'm not crazy. I've been banging my head against this wall all morning.

Comment: How is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541375/what-are-the-alternatives-to-google-analytics compliant with SO when Paypal question is not? Help me understand, please.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The fake CC numbers used in the sandbox are displayed in the test accounts setup.

See the top half of page 22 here: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/TR/tr_TR/files/developer/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide.pdf

[image: screensnip from my SandBox]

Comment: I just checked, it shows the added CC in my merchant account and NONE in my new buyer account. The screenshot in the PDF is of 2009. Earlier while adding the CC, itself used to populate the numbers not anymore. I believe there are some changes to the way paypal works.

Comment: I just now signed into my PayPal sandbox account and created a new "Preconfigured" Test account for a buyer. After it was created, I went to View Details and the Visa number was there. See update in my Answer.

Comment: I wonder why doesn't it come in mine :(
My location for test account is Singapore so i had to choose Manual method of account. Let me try your suggestion. I will write here back.

Comment: Thanks a ton Jimzie! I want to have a party with you right now :-)
It worked when using a preconfigured account.

Comment: Party On! Glad that worked.